# Visual Studio Code / Git : created branch can not be pushed

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

In visual studio code, I use the command Git > Create branch

Then, when I use Git > Push, I have an error message saying :

```
"Git: fatal: The current branch XXX has no upstream branch."
```

I know I can solve this problem by opening a command line and typing

```
git push --set-upstream origin XXX
```

My question is how can I do that directly from VSC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try git push --set-upstream origin XXX in the terminal `(CTRL+~)` of Visual Studio Code

Comment: It works thanks !

Still a pity IMHO that VSC does not allow to push the branch to the remote like VS2017 does ...